# How to put ArrayList object to parameter on getParam

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

I'm using volley library and want to put `ArrayList` type of object on parameter.
but on public `Map<String, String> getParams()`, I have to put String type.

If i use int or other type, I can convert to String type using `String.valueOf(value)` methods, but I don't know how to convert in case the type is `ArrayList`.

```
public void putParam(String key, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        params.put(key, String.valueOf(value));
    } else {
        params.put(key, "");
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {

    return params;
}
```

I always fail if I put `ArrayList<String>` type, because server detect `ArrayList` type object as String type.

Answer (score -1):

change the method to

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
     ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
                    strings.add("abc");
                    strings.add("cde");
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> params = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

         params.put("name", strings);

    return params;
    }
```

It will work.